# echo replaces \x09 with \x20

Tags: perl

A colleague noticed that when creating a file with specific nonprintable characters, perl replaces them. In this case, \x09 was replaced with \x20.

```
echo `perl -e 'print "\x41"x40 . "\xc4\x09\x40"'` > test.out
```

When you view the resulting file:

```
xxd test.out
```

you see:

```
0000000: 4141 4141 4141 4141 4141 4141 4141 4141  AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
0000010: 4141 4141 4141 4141 4141 4141 4141 4141  AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
0000020: 4141 4141 4141 4141 c420 400a            AAAAAAAA. @.
```

Notice the last 3 bytes are \xc4, \x20, \x40 instead of \xc4, \x09, \x40.  Nobody's been able to explain this to us.  The only way to get \x09 in there was to manually edit the test.out file using a hex editor.  Any thoughts?

Comment: Why do you execute perl within backticks...? Do you not know that `print` will print to standard output?

Comment: Actually I did NOT know that.  Then again, I AM a lousy programmer.  :-P

Answer (score 5):

That's the shell doing that, not Perl.  If you quote the command substitution, the tabs will be preserved:

```
echo "$(perl -e 'print "\x41"x40 . "\xc4\x09\x40"')"  > test.out
```

But I don't know why you're involving the shell at all here.  It'd be better to leave the `echo` out entirely and just run the perl directly into the file.  That means that the perl output has to include its own newline, but you can do that in a variety of ways:

```
perl -e 'print "\x41"x40 . "\xc4\x09\x40\n"' > test.out
```

or

```
perl -le 'print "\x41"x40 . "\xc4\x09\x40"' > test.out
```

or

```
perl -E 'say "\x41"x40 . "\xc4\x09\x40"' > test.out
```